# store mkdir -p command output in a variable

Tags: shell

I want to store `mkdir -p` command output in a variable.

for ex:-

```
HOME=/opt
MY_DIR=`mkdir -p $HOME/mydir`
```

so `echo $MY_DIR` should show `/opt/mydir`

but i am not getting desired output, can anyone please help?

Comment: The `mkdir` command doesn’t provide output. Since you already know what directory you want to create, why not just store that in a variable the same way you call `mkdir` with it?

Comment: `mkdir -p` does not provide any text output, which is what's needed for an invocation of `MY_DIR=$(mkdir -p $HOME/mydir)` to do the desired thing. you should do `MY_DIR="$HOME/mydir"; mkdir -p "$MY_DIR"` or something similar.

Comment: ...and as an aside -- all-caps variable names are used by POSIX-specified convention for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system, whereas variables with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Comment: @DanielH You probably meant just OP's specific usage, but without the `-p` and with `-v` argument, mkdir does print the directory it creates.

Comment: @Vasan Huh, I didn’t know about that. It doesn’t help with getting the variable to be just the directory, but it’s good to know.

Comment: @Vasan, `-v` isn't standard behavior. The *only* behavior `mkdir` is guaranteed to have is that specified in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html. (And even for GNU `mkdir`, the documentation is only that it print "a message" -- nothing about the form of that message, the language it's in, whether it includes headers or footers, any escaping for nonprintable characters, which file descriptor it's printed on; to write code that depends on it having a specific form when there are absolutely no documented guarantees regarding same would be foolhardy).

Comment: @Vasan It is standards compliant. The standard doesn’t say that `mkdir` *can’t* take an extra `-v` flag.

Comment: Right. It's a fairly small set of commands (`echo` is one) where taking extra options actually constitutes a violation.

Comment: @swapneil, ...I wonder if perhaps you're on a platform with the nonstandard `mkdir -v` extension, and you have `alias mkdir='mkdir -v'` or such defined in your interactive environment. Note that interactive aliases don't apply to scripts, and relying on nonstandard extensions in scripts is bad practice from a portability perspective regardless.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I’m not sure it would be foolhardy to count on other behavior from GNU `mkdir`. They are unlikely to change some of the things you mention (for example, the language is almost certainly going to be that specified by `LC_MESSAGES`, and probably stay on stdout).

Comment: @DanielH, I agree that sticking with the language specified by `LC_MESSAGES` is likely, but that makes us dependent on the translation table's present contents. (It's stdout right now? I don't see that documented).

Comment: @DanielH, ...perhaps I've had too much exposure to the Clojure world (where anything that's black-in-white in the documentation is guaranteed backwards-compatible forever, and *absolutely anything* that isn't explicitly specified can be changed without notice).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It’s stdout according to experimentation. I thought that was also a general GNU coding standard, but I can’t find it. I’m used to C++ where anything that isn’t documented is not only not necessarily backwards compatible, it can be inconsistent with any “reasonable” expectation like behaving the same way on different invocations of the same program. I just trust `coreutils` not to do that.

Comment: @DanielH, ...huh. Back in the old days (late 90s) before I swore off C++, my experience with compatibility *even between subsequent compiler point releases* was by no means reassuring. (I vaguely recall a place where the spec around templates and some other language feature I was using read to me as ambiguous, and egcs -- in the space of three consecutive point releases -- swung from one defensible interpretation to another and back).

Answer (score 1):

`mkdir -p` has no output (which is to say, it writes nothing to stdout).

Correct behavior is to form your directory name *before* you pass it to `mkdir`:

```
my_dir="$HOME/mydir"
mkdir -p -- "$my_dir"
```

If you wanted to capture *stderr* from `mkdir`, redirect it to stdout within your command substitution:

```
my_dir="$HOME/mydir"
mkdir_msgs=$(mkdir -p -- "$my_dir" 2>&1)
printf 'mkdir wrote the following messages: <%s>\n' "$mkdir_msgs"
```